# decoding lzo / lz4 broadcast data

Tags: python, terminal, broadcast, lzo

Post fetching UDP packets using tcpdmp on the specified port, I'm unable to decode/decompress the data. The source says this data is compressed using lz4/lzo compression algorithm.

```
    15:17:10.915293 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 3954, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 540)    192.168.200.20.27934 > 233.1.2.5.27934: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 512
0x0000:  0100 5e01 0205 001c f015 28b4 0800 4500  ..^.......(...E.
0x0010:  021c 0f72 0000 4011 f59b c0a8 c814 e901  ...r..@.........
0x0020:  0205 6d1e 6d1e 0208 f79a 0400 0001 0000  ..m.m...........
0x0030:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0x0040:  0000 1c28 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 5c00  ...(..........\.
0x0050:  0000 5c00 e86f d501 0000 0000 e86f 01d2  ..\..o.......o..
0x0060:  0002 717a 0001 0002 0000 ea0d 0000 9b14  ..qz............
0x0070:  2d00 0000 0064 0000 0000 461e 4d65 0000  -....d....F.Me..
0x0080:  9d35 d501 d8d9 d102 c034 d501 0000 5c00  .5.......4....\.
0x0090:  0000 0000 2037 0000 0000 0064 0000 9b64  .....7.....d...d
0x00a0:  0001 0000 0000 0064 0000 9b19 0001 0000  .......d........
0x00b0:  0000 024d 0000 9b14 0004 0000 0000 0001  ...M............
0x00c0:  0000 9ae7 0001 0000 0000 0048 0000 9ae2  ...........H....
0x00d0:  0001 0000 0000 000c 0000 9bb9 0001 0000  ................
0x00e0:  0000 0002 0000 9bbe 0001 0000 0000 0025  ...............%
0x00f0:  0000 9bc3 0001 0000 0000 0002 0000 9bd2  ................
0x0100:  0001 0000 0000 000a 0000 9bdc 0001 0000  ................
0x0110:  0000 0000 40da c540 0000 0000 40e8 bec0  ....@..@....@...
0x0120:  0000 0000 0083 0000 9ca9 0000 9db2 0000  ................
0x0130:  9fb5 0000 9b14 0d5f 0001 0002 0020 3ab4  ......._......:.
0x0140:  0001 0ed7 2b00 0000 008c 0000 0000 461e  ....+.........F.
0x0150:  4d75 0001 141b 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  Mu..............
0x0160:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 018a  ................
0x0170:  0001 0ed7 0002 0000 0000 00af 0001 0ed2  ................
0x0180:  0002 0000 0000 0033 0001 0ebe 0001 0000  .......3........
0x0190:  0000 0343 0001 0eb9 0001 0000 0000 0096  ...C............
0x01a0:  0001 0eb4 0001 0000 0000 000a 0001 0efa  ................
0x01b0:  0001 0000 0000 007d 0001 0f04 0002 0000  .......}........
0x01c0:  0000 0032 0001 0f09 0001 0000 0000 0031  ...2...........1
0x01d0:  0001 0f13 0001 0000 0000 01a4 0001 0f18  ................
0x01e0:  0006 0000 0000 0000 40ee 6e20 0000 0000  ........@.n.....
0x01f0:  4101 c8d8 0000 0000 0000 0001 0b17 0001  A...............
0x0200:  0c5c 0001 1b2a 0001 0b30 0000 0000 0000  .\...*...0......
0x0210:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0x0220:  0000 0000 0000 0100 0000                 ..........
```

---

This is example of one packet containing the data. What is the expected way to decode this?